# Django / Python dict values return each letter as item

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I've got a problem which I just can't figure out. I've got a dictionary which I get from choices of a django form:

**forms.py**

```
 class testForm(forms.Form):
     TEST_CHOICES = (
         ("1", "One"),
         ("2", "Two"),
         ("3", "Three"),
     )

     test_choice_field = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=TEST_CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple)
```

In my views.py I iterate through that dict of choices and try to return those choices in a string like this: "One / Two / Three"

```
 def test_func(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
         form = testForm(request.POST)
         if form.is_valid():
             test_choice_field = form.cleaned_data["test_choice_field"]
             empty_string = ""
             for numbers in test_choice_field:
                 empty_string += dict(form.fields['test_choice_field'].choices)[numbers]
             subject = "[{}] is the Number you are looking for.".format(empty_string)
```

What I wish for is that my "subject" holds the string "One / Two is the Number you are looking for", depending on which checkbox the user has checked. So if he/she picks all three checkboxes he get: "One / Two / Three is the Number you are looking for" and if it's only one "Two is the Number you are looking for" etc

Now I simply just wanted to do a **" / ".join(empty_string)**, but ended up getting this "O/n/e/T/w/o is the...."

What am I doing wrong? And please don't remove the **" / ".join()**, I know I could do something with format(), but I'm especially looking for a solution using .join() :)

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Join a list of strings instead of a string.

Comment: @Ryan you mean "/".join(numbers) ? Since they're basically strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the following changes

```
l = []
for numbers in test_choice_field:
    l.append(dict(form.fields['test_choice_field'].choices)[numbers])
subject = "[{}] is the Number you are looking for.".format('/'.join(l))
```

Problem with your solution was that you were trying to call `join` on a string. 
`join` takes an iterable of strings and joins it using the connector character. If you pass a string to it, i considers it as an iterable and joins each character in the string with the connector character.

In your case, it need to be a `list` of strings.

Comment: Please add to the answer what the problem was and how you solved it.